# highlight hovered row in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) 
with the --highlight className that highlightes the hovered table row. 
I would like to customize the css of the highlighted row, but I could not find the right class to I need override so to do that. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the class you want is `.ReactTable.-highlight`.

[React-table github styles](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/blob/master/src/index.styl#L197)

Comment: Hi, the link is invalid. Could you please check it? Thanks.